# How to stop snakemake from adding non file endings to wildcards when using expand function? (.g.vcf fails, .vcf works)

Tags: snakemake

Adding .g.vcf instead of .vcf after the variable in expand rule is somehow adding the .g to a wildcard in another module

I have tried the following in the all rule :

```
{stuff}.g.vcf 
{stuff}"+"g.vcf" 
{stuff}_var"+".g.vcf"
{stuff}.t.vcf
```

all fail but {stuff}.gvcf or {stuff}.vcf work

Error:

InputFunctionException in line 21 of snake_modules/mark_duplicates.snakefile:
KeyError: 'Mother.g'
Wildcards:
lane=Mother.g

Code:

```
LANES = config["list2"].split()

rule all:
    input:
         expand(projectDir+"results/alignments/variants/{stuff}.g.vcf", stuff=LANES)


rule mark_duplicates:
    """ this will mark duplicates for bam files from the same sample and library """
    input:
        get_lanes
    output:
        projectDir+"results/alignments/markdups/{lane}.markdup.bam"
    log:
        projectDir+"logs/"+stamp+"_{lane}_markdup.log"
    shell:
        " input=$(echo '{input}' |sed -e s'/ / I=/g') && java -jar /home/apps/pipelines/picard-tools/CURRENT MarkDuplicates I=$input O={projectDir}results/alignments/markdups/{wildcards.lane}.markdup.bam M={projectDir}results/alignments/markdups/{wildcards.lane}.markdup_metrics.txt &> {log}"
```

I want my final output to have the {stuff}.g.vcf notation. Please note this output is created in another snake module but the error appears in the mark duplicates which is before the other module.

I have tried multiple changes but it is the .g.vcf in the all rule that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *guess* is that `{lane}` is interpreted as a regular expression and it's capturing more than it should. Try adding before `rule all`:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    stuff= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in LANES]),
    lane= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in LANES])
```

(See also this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snakemake/wVlJW9X-9EU)